# Gimp selection vanished

Tags: gimp

I have been using GIMP for many years and suddenly the selection outline - dashed line has stopped working.
it does make the selection and I can cut away the invisible selection but I cannot see it.
I toggled it in the view menu and under preferences... nothing.
Also if I convert the selection to a path and try and stroke it, nothing appears

Comment: [Check preferences](https://imgur.com/a/v0QPjRI), reset if necessary. Last resort might be a totally clean reinstall of GIMP. Other than that, tech support is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.  Might depend on your setup/OS/version/maybe a corrupt installation, who knows!

Answer (score 2):

If you are on OSX Big Sur, this is a [known problem](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/5952).

You can check your selection with the [QuickMask](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-window-qmask-button.html) or the [Selection editor](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-dialog.html).

Not that when you do `Select ➤ To path` and the `Edit ➤ Stroke path` only one half of the path is drawn since the other half/side lies outside the selection. If the path is thin (1px) there is not much left.